# Ionic-2-Calendar Month View Event Detail Template - How do i access anything about the event that is not time?

Tags: ionic-framework, calendar, ionic2-calendar

Im using ionic2-calendar to create a calendar in my app. The default event viewer only has time and title but I want to add description and other fields as well. Since I cant change the default, I looked around for some ways to make my own. It turns out that ionic has things called [templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-calendar). I'm using the month view so the template of interest for me is this one.

```
<ng-template #template let-showEventDetail="showEventDetail" let-selectedDate="selectedDate" let-noEventsLabel="noEventsLabel">
    ... 
    </ng-template>

    <calendar ... [monthviewEventDetailTemplate]="template"></calendar>
```

The issue I have is that I dont know how to access event info. My events have a "desc" field that holds a description of the event but idk how to access it here. Anyone familiar with this? I basically want something like `{{event.title}}` to give me the event's title.

Answer (score 1):

You can access all event details by `selectedDate.events` and also you can add your own property to your events through handle it on your functions.

```
<ng-template #template let-showEventDetail="showEventDetail" let-selectedDate="selectedDate" let-noEventsLabel="noEventsLabel">
     <calendar-event [events]="selectedDate.events"></calendar-event>
 </ng-template>
```

In the other hand you can define more then one template for one calendar. For example if you want handle calender date view then use `[monthviewDisplayEventTemplate]="dateTemplate"`

```
<ng-template #dateTemplate let-view="view" let-row="row" let-col="col">
            <span class="event-label">
              {{view.dates[row*7+col].label}}
                <ion-badge *ngIf="!view.dates[row*7+col].secondary" class="event-count-badge" color="danger">{{myEventsCount[view.dates[row*7+col].label] || ""}}</ion-badge>
            </span>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #detailTemplate let-showEventDetail="showEventDetail" let-selectedDate="selectedDate" let-noEventsLabel="noEventsLabel">
            <calendar-event [events]="selectedDate.events"></calendar-event>
</ng-template>
            <calendar 
                      [monthviewDisplayEventTemplate]="dateTemplate"
                      [monthviewEventDetailTemplate]="detailTemplate"
                      [eventSource]="eventSource"
                      [calendarMode]="calendar.mode"
                      [currentDate]="calendar.currentDate"
                      [showEventDetail]="true"
                      (onCurrentDateChanged)="onCurrentDateChanged($event)"
                      (onEventSelected)="onEventSelected($event)"
                      (onTitleChanged)="onViewTitleChanged($event)"
                      (onTimeSelected)="onTimeSelected($event)">
            </calendar>
```